# ASP.NET MVC - updates using partial views, or JSON/Knockout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I'm trying to find a line (or pattern), when to update pages through partial views and when "only" to use JSON and JS library like Knockout.

For example, I have a sorted list of items and several different views (perspectives) on this list (e.g., one with thumbnails, one with bells, one with whistles), and user can switch between these views.

One option is that every view is rendered by partial view - so when user chooses a view (perspective), corresponding partial view is downloaded through ajax (controller -> partial view).

The opposite option is to initially get the list as a JSON and render the view using e.g. Knockout - but I feel that this goes against MVC - action on controller doesn't produce a view (or partial view), but in this case it produces a JSON list. In many cases it's clear when to use partial view, and when just JSON - my rule generally was that view (HTML markup) is  View and through JSON I only modify the HTML markup.

Now I'm not sure where the line should be drawn - using more extensively JSON/Knockout results in more responsible web application and less traffic (client downloads the data just once and the actual view is rendered/updated on the client's side), but I'm not sure it's "right".

So, when do update your pages through partial views and when using JSON/JS?

EDIT:

In other words - in ASP.NET MVC + Razor scenario, is there any benefit - except offloading the server workload to the browser - in using client-side templates?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be flagged as an opinionated question, but I'll give my thoughts anyway. Both techniques work, but I do agree that pure MVVM wouldn't utilize partial views.

I do like partial views because of Razor, intellisense, and its built-in ability to make use of data validations though. Handling validation in MVVM way seems much more cumbersome to me.

Comment: I've recently taken to creating partial views which render Knockout templates. So for, I have found that it's easier to write the raw HTML elements rather than leaning on Razor and the HtmlHelper; though I do miss the simplicity of MVC's validation. However, as opposed to writing templates into plain old .js files where Razor does not exist or just in-line on the page sacrificing usability, the partial page adds a bit more power and flexibility while maintaining module reuse.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of application you are planning:

If you are building a website that needs to be crawled by a search engine you should build a non Javascript version and [Hijax it with jquery](http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/ajax-calls-with-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc)

MVVM libraries like KO are used for Single Page Applications. They are not crawlable by search engines (at least not out of the box ). They are also harder to track with tracking solutions.

Comment: This is good information that I don't often think about when deciding on my application architecture.